# How to get notified in React-Native when a device goes offline?

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator, offline

I tried to listen to the `isConnected` event of `NetInfo`, but somehow this only fires once, shortly after the app starts. When I deactivate my connection it doesn't fire again.

I tried this in the iOS simulator, so it could be a simulator issue, but I'm not sure.

```
...
componentWillMount() {
  NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
    "connectionChange",
    this.handleConnectionChange
  );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
    "connectionChange",
    this.handleConnectionChange
  );
}

handleConnectionChange = online => this.setState({ online });
...
```

Comment: How did you deactivate the connection? I am currently using the `eventListener` and it triggers in the simulator when I disconnect my Mac.

Comment: yes, I clicked to deactivate wifi on the top menu

Comment: Post the relevant code

Comment: okay, updated my question

Comment: Hmmm, that seems to work for me. How do you know it's only being called once, what does `this.state.online` tie to?

Comment: Did you deactivate wifi in MacOS or in the simulator? Have you tried setting the emulator to airplane mode instead?

Comment: Hm, somehow airplane mode worked. thank you :)